# Hash functions for strings

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I have to develop a function which works fine for three keys: vehicle license_no, issue_date, and last_name. My code works fine for issue_date and last_name but results in a lot of collisions for license no. Example license_no `L1-0015338`.

I'm new to hash functions and don't know which kind of hash function to use.

```
int hash3(char* s, int max)
{
    int prime = 20000;
    char* c;
    unsigned long number, column=1, hash, i;

    for (i = hash = 0; *s; i++, s++)
    {
        column *= (*s);
        prime = nextPrime(prime);
        hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) ^ column) * prime;
    }

    return (int)((hash) % max);
}
```

Comment: 20000 is not a prime number

Comment: the function next prime will return the prime number greater than passed value

Comment: `i` and `c` are unused, Also get rid of the signed ints. Why do you think you need the primes?

Comment: And what is the value of `max` that you pass to the function when you're hashing the license number?

Comment: Also, where did you get this hash function? Rather than trying to roll your own, why not adopt something that has been proven to work well? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions gives you some very good options to choose from.